# R: phyper understanding phyper

Tags: r, statistics

I am trying to calculate hypergeometric probabilities using phyper in R, and notice a strange behavior.  I am looking at gene set overlap probabilities, and in one case, there are no "successful draws," so:

```
x=0
m=430
n=19500
k=2
```

Since in general I'm looking for over-enrichment I use:

```
phyper(0,600,19000,2,lower.tail=FALSE)
```

and get 0.043 which appears to be significant.
 However, choosing two "n" genes should have probability of

```
19500/19930*19499/19929=0.957
```

so, shouldn't the phyper result be greater than 0.957?

Comment: From the docs: it looks like you need to switch `lower.tail` to `TRUE`. See arguments listed in https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/Hypergeometric.html.

Comment: Doesn't that test for "under enrichment?" I want to test for "over enrichment," even though that doesn't really make sense when x = 0.  In most of my cases x>0, but I am just trying to understand the result when x=0.

Comment: I don't know the specifics of the subject, but if you're expecting to get `0.957` and you get `0.043` (`= 1 - 0.957`), switching the `lower.tail` argument will get you what you expect.

Comment: That's the part I don't understand.  It's like it's giving me the lower tail when I believe I really need the upper tail, and should be getting the upper tail since lower.tail=FALSE. In this particular case, the problem is supposed to be formulated to ask, "what is the probability of getting 0 or more successful draws." Am I wrong that that would be the upper tail?